# Find the sum which is not possible

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set having the $N$ numbers starting from $1$ to $N$.

I know the maximum sum can be formed from members of this set is $N(N+1)/2$. Now i am giving $K$ numbers that are removed  I have to find the minimum sum which is not possible. How can i calculate it?

For example: $N=5$, $K = \{3,5\}$ so $8$ is not possible.

Comment: but in your example, $8>7=1+2+4$ so not interesting. Maybe "N=4, K={1,3}, 5 is not possible"?

Comment: @Joffan could not get you ? 8 is the smallest number which can not be formed

Comment: Yes, but it's just greater than sum of the remaining allowed numbers in the set, {1,2,4}. In fact the use of "N=5" is a bit suspect because you've removed 5. In my example the remaining numbers {2,4} sum to 6 but 5 is not possible.

Comment: @Joffan ok sorry for this !!! would you please explain me a  concept

Comment: added some exploration in a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a variable $i=1$

Now lets take another variable $Answer$ which will be our final answer.

Now, Start iterating variable $i$ one by one , and add it to $Answer$ variable(only when $i$ is not present in $K$ numbers).

Finally stop this process when your $Answer >i $  or $i=N$ satisfies.

Value of $Answer$ is your final answer.

Comment: proof !!! why this

Answer (score 0):

Some exploration:

The example given in the question (N=5, K={3,5}, answer 8) is above the remaining sum $M$,
$$M = N(N+1)/2 - \sum_iK_i$$

I suggest that $N$ should not be removed (since this just knocks the original set span down). Then we can proceed by eliminating cases from the low end upwards, to see if there are any values less than $M$ that cannot be achieved by summing members of the reduced set.

- If 1 is removed, then obviously the answer is 1, so we can note that and then restrict attention to cases where 1 is not removed.
- If 2 is removed, then the answer is 2. So we will consider cases where 1 and 2 remain.
- The sum of 3 is now covered. However if 3 is retained, it also covers sums of 4,5 and 6. including 7 would continue the cover up to 13.
- If 3 and 4 is absent, the answer is 4. If 3 is removed and 4 retained, sums {5,6,7} are covered. Also retaining 8 would provide cover up to 15. This suggests (correctly) that we can cover up to $M$ by retaining the powers of 2, although the examination of 3 above illustrates that this is not the only way to do so.

In general for a large set there will be some cases where we can quickly establish that all the values up to $M$ are covered, but there may also be  cases where that is hard to establish or there is in fact an uncovered value less than $M$.